# Onclick que me llame a una funcion

Tags: javascript, array, dom, onclick, innerhtml

Tengo que hacer una tienda online. Hice un array de productos, y despues un array de cada categoria de productos. (gorras, remeras, zapatos, barbijos...)
Lo lleve al html de la siguiente forma detallada debajo de todo..

Lo que necesito es que al apretar el boton VER MAS (esta en productos.html),  me lleve a otro html en el que solo figure ese producto seleccionado pero con mas informacion (detalle.html). Como hago la vinculacion ?? Tengo que hacer un array nuevo con la informacion adicional que quiero de cada producto, que me lleve a detalle.html?

---

```
const listaGorras = document.getElementById('gorras')

gorras.forEach(prod => {
    let card = document.createElement('div')
    card.classList.add('col')
    card.innerHTML = `
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" style="padding-top: 1.5rem;">
        <div class="card conLink" onclick="verProducto(1)">
            <img src="${prod.imagen}" class="card-img-top welcome-imagen" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title welcome-titulo" alt="">${prod.nombre}</h5>
            <span class="card-title welcome-precio" alt="" >${prod.precio}</span >
            <div>
            <div  style="display: inline-block;"></div>
            <div  style="display: inline-block;"></div>
            <div  style="display: inline-block;"></div>                                        
            </div>

            <div class="btn btn-primary ">VER M&Aacute;S</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
`
listaGorras.appendChild(card)
```

})

---

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner el índice del elemento como parámetro de la función verProducto y luego obtener el elemento con ese índice para pasar los parámetros del objeto por url con querystring:

- Reemplaza foreach por map para obtener i

```
gorras.map((prod, i)=>{
...
<div class="card conLink" onclick="verProducto(i)">
```

- Ahora en la función verProducto:

```
function verProducto(i){
var prod= gorras[i];
window.location.href = "http://www.page.com/?nombre"+prod.nombre+"&precio"+prod.precio;

}
```

En la otra página obtienes los parámetros así:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
var nombre = params.get("nombre")
```